Add new dapp to blowfish whitelist
How I can add my new dapp to blowfish whitelist. I'm a new solana developer. and don't know anyone in community.

Good luck with that. I submitted and responded to one of their staff members with my app details in April and still haven't received a response. From my experience if you don't have someone to vouch for you or if they don't like you, you are pretty much left in the dark. Ugly side of Solana for sure.

I also encounter the same problem, how to solve it?
